# How to overwrite version of transitive dependency Groovy from Thymeleaf 1.5.8.RELEASE in Spring Boot using Gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, groovy, dependencies

I'm kinda new in the Gradle world. As part of a security audit we are having, we were told the following dependency in one of your Gradle projects:

```
compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '1.5.8.RELEASE')
```

is using the transitive dependency for Groovy 2.4.7, but since that version has some security vulnerabilities (https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2016-6497), we need to override the Groovy version for a newer one.

This is the dependency tree for that section:

```
org.springframework.boot.spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.4.1.RELEASE ( /opt/whitehat/satellite/applications/9400/src/10280/pom.xml [line 36, column 15] ) 
    - nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0 ( /opt/whitehat/satellite/applications/9400/src/10280/pom.xml [line 36, column 15] ) 
        - org.codehaus.groovy.groovy-2.4.7
```

How to override the Groovy version from 2.4.7 to a higher version?

I have tried the following but it's not working:

```
compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '1.5.8.RELEASE') {
    exclude(module: 'groovy')
}

compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.12'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is because of security concerns, I'd use a resolution strategy to make sure noone accidentally adds this version to any configuration like this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        dependencySubstitution {
            substitute module('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.7') with module('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.12')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked perfectly. I will include that resolution in all the projects that the auditors scanned to update the Groovy version when using Thymeleaf.