# groovy-all:3.0.8 in my build.gradle is downloading different jars versions

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

After adding `groovie-all:3.0.8` into my `build.gradle`, the downloaded jars are in different version as shown bellow. Each of this jars has its `3.0.8` version and I don't know why they aren't download instead.

[image: groovy-all jars]

Appreciate any help

Thanx

Comment: Try setting the property `groovy.version` to 3.0.8.

Comment: smells like dependency restriction in gradle plugin of spring boot or whatever framework you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Groovy 2.5, `groovy-all` is just a pom which brings in the equivalent component jars, see the according [release notes](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.5.html). This explains that you see no `groovy-all`.

Regarding the version numbers: `spring-boot` defines the grooy version, you can print it with:

```
ext {
    // versions taken from Spring BOM
    GROOVY_VERSION = dependencyManagement.importedProperties['groovy.version']
    println GROOVY_VERSION
}
```

and I expect it is 2.5.13 which for example is included by [Spring Boot Version 2.3.4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html#dependency-versions). Unfortunately you didn't specify your used Spring version.

With Spring Boot you include Groovy normally just with

```
compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all"
```

without a version number since Spring Boot defines the version.

So the question is how to override the provided Spring version - alternatively you can increase the used Spring version to get a more recent Groovy version.

To override the Spring version just exclude Groovy, eg see this SO posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972674/3181392
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47355002/734687

E.g. use:

```
ext['groovy.version'] = '3.0.8'
```

To see which component included the wrong version you can execute the Gradle task "dependencies" (find it in IDEA under the help categegory). In this answer I assumed it was Spring (and I am sure it was).